# Cannot boot as /sbin/init is reported missing

Tags: boot

I use Ubuntu 14.04. A few days ago, I logged off, then my computer was unresponsive as I tried to log back on. I do not recall installing any software or changing any setting that could have caused this. Since then, whenever I have tried to boot, I receive the following error messages:

```
mount: mounting /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root on /root failed: invalid argument
mount: mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /sys on /root/sys failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /proc on /root/proc failed: No such file or directory
Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init
No init found. Try passing init= bootarg.


BusyBox v1.21.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.21.0-1ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

Something similar seems to have happened to other users before:

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159554/ubuntu-12-04-wont-load-hangs-at-busybox-v1-18-5-initramfs) post recommends Ubuntu Boot-Repair. I tried it, selected "recommended repair", and received a message that it was successful. However, after a restart, the error message appeared as before. The log of Boot-Repair can be found [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/15007879/).

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17647/target-filesystem-doesnt-have-requested-sbin-init?rq=1), I found the suggestion of booting from a live disk and using `fsck -f`. The command came back without an error code, but the booting problem persisted as before. Likewise when I tried `e2fsck`, as suggested [here](https://tdapower.wordpress.com/2011/07/11/solution-for-ubuntu-target-filesystem-doesnt-have-sbininit/).

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450117/cant-boot-wubi-after-upgrading-to-14-04-from-12-04-target-filesystem-doesnt), someone suggests editing the Grub configuration. I tried it, again to no effect.

If anyone could come up with something else I can try, I would much appreciate it.

EDIT: After posting this, I stumbled upon the recommendation that I use Rescatux to post a log of the boot info script. Here it is:

paste.ubuntu.com/15049548/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution after some trial and error. The problem turned out to be that I had encrypted my hard drive with LUKS.

Here are the steps I followed to fix it. Some of these might have been superfluous, since I kept trying different things until it worked, but now that the error is fixed, I can't go back to test which steps were inessential.

1. `sudo fdisk -l` to learn the name of my encrypted partition; here, `/dev/sda5`.
2. `sudo modprobe dm-crypt`
3. `sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda5 crypt1`. At this point, I had to enter my passphrase.
4. `sudo vgscan --mknodes`. This will yield a volume name. Mine was `ubuntu-vg`.
5. `sudo vgchange -ay`
6. `sudo fsck -vy /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root`.

After rebooting, everything worked normally.